# Beamer: Reserving space for video overlay

Tags: beamer, presentations, shapepar

For preparing a video lecture, I would like to have a frame template on which I can reserve a rectangular area, on which I want to place later a camera overlay for screencasting.
Ideally, the template also has the aspect ratio 16:9, to allow for a FullHD recording.
The size of the rectangular area should be between around 1/9 of the total area.

```
|----------------------------------|
|              Title               |
|----------------------------------|
|                                  |
|                                  |
|        CONTENT      |------------|
|                     |   video    |
|                     |  overlay   |
|---------------------|------------|
```

A modification of the *default* scheme would be sufficient since the corporate scheme builds on it.

Comment: IMHO you should draw with TikZ, for example, a rectangle of the correct dimensions in lower right corner. Then prepare all you slides taking care of don't write in the rectangle. In the end, for the final version, you just delete the rectangle from all you slides. Et voilà that's it.

Comment: (And I apologize for assuming @vipa's gender in my bounty, but I can't edit it!) There should be a way to play with `\setbeamertemplate{footline}` in some way to get the content to flow around this overlay, but I can't find it…

Comment: @Clément No problem, by the way I'm a male. For your question I've found a the package [shapepar](https://ctan.org/pkg/shapepar) of Donald Arseneau but I don't know if it work in Beamer class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO you should draw with TikZ, for example, a rectangle of the correct dimensions in lower right corner. Then prepare all your slides taking care of don't write in the rectangle. In the end, for the final version, you just delete the rectangle from all your slides. Et voilà that's it.

This is the very simple code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\forCam}{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[red] (current page.south east) rectangle +(-5,3); %adjust this values by trial and errors for fit your camera overlay 
}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
\forCam % comment this line for delete the rectangle in the final version
Content of the slide

\tikz[remember picture, overlay]
\node at ($(current page.south east)!0.5!($(current page.south east)+(-5,3)$)$) {Don't write here!};
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: slide for overlay camera]

Comment: Thanks, I combined this with adjusting the background image in beamer slides as explained for instance here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78464/background-image-in-beamer-slides

Comment: You may also use `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` to put content at the exact position in one compilation.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative or addon to the existing answer of leaving the responsibility to the author, refining the margins a bit can help to accomplish this more easily. The following simply shifts the content block a bit to the left.

```
    \makeatletter
    \setbeamersize{text margin left=0.75\beamer@leftmargin}
    \setbeamersize{text margin right=3\beamer@rightmargin}
    \makeatother
```

Additionally, using beamer's `aspectratio` parameter (set to `169` or `1610`) can create more space on the sides and makes sure your presentations/videos match most viewing devices.

Be aware that some elements might resize unintendedly, e.g., `\includegraphics` referring to `\textwidth` with either these methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `\logo{...}` macro to mark an appropriately sized region so you know which area you want to keep clean of text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\logo{\color{red}\rule{4cm}{3cm}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```