# Beamer template Talking head

Tags: beamer, graphics, footnotes, backgrounds, sidebar

I have some beamer slides for a lecture in 16:9 format and I want to record videos for this lecture. In the video, I'd like to add myself as taking the head into the slides in the bottom right corner. To do so, I want to change my current latex beamer template so that it has a placeholder in the bottom right corner where I will put my "talking head". I want to make sure that the text from my current slides does not overlap the placeholder and that the current text nicely aligns around the placeholder (see figure below). This means I cannot just use a background image as the text would not align around the placeholder for the talking head.
Of course, I might have to go through each slide afterward to see if adding the placeholder messed up something but this is fine.
Any suggestions on how I can add such a placeholder to each slide?

[image: floating text]

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560068/beamer-designing-slide and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625748/beamer-reserving-space-for-video-overlay-automatically

Comment: related, but manual: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/533361/36296