# Simple box in beamer

Tags: tcolorbox, framed, themes

I'm looking for a beamer theme with a simple box around each frame. Just a coloured rectangle, really. I tried to frame each slide myself with tcolorbox, but I can only make it start below the frame title. How would I go about making a box like the one in the picture below? Or is there a preset theme that I haven't found yet?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Background image in beamer slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78464). You may want to replace the image insertion code with a `tcolorbox` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code could be a solution. It draws a rectangular `TikZ` node in background. You have to compile twice to see the rectangular border.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
    \node[draw=blue, thick, minimum width=.975\paperwidth, minimum height=.95\paperheight] at (current page.center){};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Testing Background Image}
    Hello!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]